# Flutter - Why image obtained from camera controller is wider than it was on cameraPreview?

Tags: android, flutter, camera

I'm working with [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package on flutter and I noticed that image obtained from `takePicture()` function is wider than it was shown in preview mode. Moreover, picture taken vertically seems square. Should I postprocess it myself? And is it the same in native android development?

Build method code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder<void>(
            future: _initializeControllerFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {

              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return Stack(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Positioned.fill(
                      child: _getCameraPreview(context),
                    ),
                    new Positioned.fill(
                      child: new Opacity(
                          opacity: 0.7,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            _layoutPath,
                            scale: 5,
                            fit: BoxFit.none,
                            alignment: Alignment(0.2, 0.1),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              } else {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: BottomAppBar(
              color: Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0),
              child: _getBottomAppBarRow(context),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _getCameraPreview(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final deviceRatio = size.width / size.height;
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: _controller.value.aspectRatio / deviceRatio,
      child: Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
          child: CameraPreview(_controller),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Shutter button code

```
final shutterButton = Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: AppColors.white,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.camera,
          color: AppColors.white,
          size: 24,
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            await _initializeControllerFuture;

            final path = join(
              (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
              '${DateTime.now()}.png',
            );
            await _controller.takePicture(path);

            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DisplayPictureScreen(imagePath: path),
              ),
            );
            _controller.dispose();
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
```

**EDIT:**

Camera controller initialization code:

```
CameraController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;
  var _firstCamera;
  var _layoutPath = 'images/cie-on-50.png';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    availableCameras().then((cameras) {
      setState(() {
        _firstCamera = cameras.first;
        _controller = CameraController(_firstCamera, ResolutionPreset.high);
        _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the underlying CameraPlugin class that implements Java side of **CameraController**, tries to keep aspect ratio of preview and capture images consistent. Often, in native code, people forget about this, because the native API does nothing to help the developer keep picture and preview aspect ratios in sync. This can result in what you observed, captured Jpeg of 16:9 with preview of 4:3, and the field of view of such still picture will be wider than the preview.

But as you can see in the linked Java code, Flutter camera is actually written (almost) correctly. One catch is that [comparing floats](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/3ddc2fe2ad97d5574d082b9b5f35f4d06c82a925/packages/camera/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/CameraPlugin.java#L417) could lead to nasty rounding effects. Their list of **goodEnough** preview resolutions may be screwed up because they require that the preview width be less that screen width (in portait mode, it could be as low as 720).

At any rate, you can check the preview size returned by **initialize()**, and most likely it is 16:9, same as the Jpeg.

BTW, I believe that you use **.png** extension by mistake, and the actual image is saved as Jpeg on the sdcard.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've added controller init code

Comment: What device(s) did you try? It might be useful to run [Camera2 Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hvt.camera2test) or similar app and understand what the camera API actually says to flutter.

Comment: It is Meizu MX6 on android 7.1.1. I'll try to use the app on other devices in order to be sure that it does not depend on device type

Comment: Also, check the camera info to understand whether the supported picture and preview resolutions are reasonable.